# How to alternate XML Elements during XML serialization in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd

I have an XSD schema that has been given to us by a data provider. I cannot modify it. I generated the classes using the XSD.exe command line tool. For everything it works perfectly, I can create my objects in C#, serialize it in XML and validate it against the XSD.

I have a problem with a small portion of it. The expected output is:

```
    <Physical>
        <Class>P</Class>
        <Capacity>14</Capacity>
        <Class>J</Class>
        <Capacity>64</Capacity>
        <Class>W</Class>
        <Capacity>1</Capacity>
        <Class>Y</Class>
        <Capacity>2</Capacity>
    </Physical>
    <Saleable Protected="true">
        <Class>P</Class>
        <Capacity>14</Capacity>
        <Class>J</Class>
        <Capacity>64</Capacity>
        <Class>W</Class>
        <Capacity>1</Capacity>
        <Class>Y</Class>
        <Capacity>2</Capacity>
    </Saleable>
```

As you can see, the child elements of Physical and Sealable alternate (i.e. Class, then Capacity, then Class, then Capacity, etc.).

This is the code of the class that was generated by XSD.exe:

```
public partial class ClassA
{
    private string[] classField;

    private Integerctype[] capacityField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Class", DataType = "token")]
    public string[] Class
    {
        get
        {
            return this.classField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.classField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Capacity", IsNullable = true)]
    public Integerctype[] Capacity
    {
        get
        {
            return this.capacityField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.capacityField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And the output I receive after the serialization:

```
<Physical>
    <Class>P</Class>
    <Class>J</Class>
    <Class>W</Class>
    <Class>Y</Class>
    <Capacity>14</Capacity>
    <Capacity>64</Capacity>
    <Capacity>1</Capacity>
    <Capacity>2</Capacity>
</Physical>
<Saleable>
    <Class>P</Class>
    <Class>J</Class>
    <Class>W</Class>
    <Class>Y</Class>
    <Capacity>14</Capacity>
    <Capacity>64</Capacity>
    <Capacity>1</Capacity>
    <Capacity>2</Capacity>
</Saleable>
```

As you can see, we lost the alternation between Class and Capacity...

I tried to use the Order property of the XmlElementAttribute: the Class property was decorated with Order = 1, and the Capacity property was decorated with Order = 2, but it did not help. Example:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Class", DataType = "token", Order = 1)]
public string[] Class
```

During the validation, with or without the Order property, I receive errors as follow:

> The element 'Physical' in namespace 'xxx' has invalid child element
>   'Class' in namespace 'xxx'. List of possible elements expected:
>   'Capacity' in namespace 'xxx'.

Finally, here is the portion of the XSD:

```
<xsd:element name="ClassA" minOccurs="0">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="Physical" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>True, physical class A configuration</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xsd:element name="Class" type="CabinClass.type" />
                        <xsd:element name="Capacity" type="Integer.ctype" nillable="true" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:attributeGroup ref="Array.attgroup" />
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="Saleable" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Class A configuration for sales purposes</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xsd:element name="Class" type="CabinClass.type" />
                        <xsd:element name="Capacity" type="Integer.ctype" nillable="true" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:attributeGroup ref="Array.attgroup" />
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:all>
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="Container.attgroup" />
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

My guess is that it is related to the presence of xsd:sequence. But as I said, I do not want to modify the XSD as it is provided by a data provider and we must ensure that the XML we generate is fully compatible.

Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Order does not make a difference with xml, but because of the schema issue order is very important in YOUR case.  Best way of insuring the order is to write a custom serialization using either XDocument or XmlDocument methods.  You can also use XmlWriter.

Comment: @jdweng, thanks for your input. Yes it is weird that they are expecting these elements to be in a precise order, but that's how it is unfortunately. A custom serializer is probably not the best option here for us, since the XSD and the generated XML files are huge. We are trying to use the standard serialization and customize the classes generated by XSD.exe only where it is needed for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: If the files is huge then you are going to get an out of memory error using standard serialization.  So you are going to have to use XmlReader.  No other choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplified code could be this:

```
public class Physical
{
    [XmlElement("Capacity", typeof(int))]
    [XmlElement("Class", typeof(string))]
    public object[] Items { get; set; }
}
```

This will ensure correct deserialization and give the serialization of the elements in the order in which they are placed in the array.

A working version might look like this:

```
public class Physical
{
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [XmlElement("Capacity", typeof(int))]
    [XmlElement("Class", typeof(string))]
    public object[] Items
    {
        get
        {
            object[] items = new object[Class.Length * 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i += 2)
            {
                items[i] = Class[i / 2];
                items[i + 1] = Capacity[i / 2];
            }
            return items;
        }
        set
        {
            Class = new string[value.Length / 2];
            Capacity = new int[value.Length / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i += 2)
            {
                Class[i / 2] = (string)value[i];
                Capacity[i / 2] = (int)value[i + 1];
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string[] Class { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int[] Capacity { get; set; }
}
```

Change `int` to `Integerctype`, add `DataType` parameter.

Similarly, change the second class.